# Why after defining hashCode() and equals() my code still compares links

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have 2 classes Student and Group. Group has Set of Students. `hashCode()` and `equals()` overriden for both.

Then I populate `Set<Student>` in Group. Why two same groups (same id, name, `Set<Student>` etc) are different? When I delete `Set<Student>` from `hashCode()` and `equals()` of group the groups become the same. But that's two identical `Set<Student>`. I suppose that in case of `Set<Student>` it compares the links. I don't understand this, for example `String name` is an Object and `Set<Student>` is an `Object`. When I include both to `hashCode()` and `equals()` it compares actual value for `String name` and links for `Set<Student>`.

**Student.java:**

```
public class Student {  

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {     
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }   

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!getClass().equals(other.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        Student castOther = (Student) other;
        return Objects.equals(id, castOther.id) 
                && Objects.equals(firstName, castOther.firstName)
                && Objects.equals(lastName, castOther.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, firstName, lastName);
    }       
}
```

**Group.java:**

```
public class Group {

    private int id;
    private String name;    
    private Set<Student> students;

    public Group(int id, String name) {     
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!getClass().equals(other.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        Group castOther = (Group) other;
        return Objects.equals(id, castOther.id) 
                && Objects.equals(name, castOther.name)
                && Objects.equals(students, castOther.students);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, students);
    }
}
```

**GroupDaoImpl.java:**

```
Set<Group> retrieveAll() throws DaoException {      
    String sql = "select * from groups;";               
    Set<Group> groupSet = new HashSet<>();

    try (Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
            connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {         
        preparedStatement.execute();
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();         

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("group_id");
            String name = resultSet.getString("name");              
            Group group = new Group(id, name);              
            group.setStudents(studentDao.retrieveByGroupId(id));                
            groupSet.add(group);
        }                       
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        throw new DaoException(e);          
    } 
    return groupSet;
}
```

**StudentDaoImpl.java:**

```
Set<Student> retrieveByGroupId(int groupId) throws DaoException {       
    String sql = "select * from student where group_id = ?;";       
    Set<Student> studentSet = new HashSet<>();

    try (Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, groupId);
        preparedStatement.execute();            
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("student_id");
            String firstName = resultSet.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = resultSet.getString("last_name");             
            Student student = new Student(id, firstName, lastName);             
            studentSet.add(student);
        }                       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException(e);          
    } 
    return studentSet;
}
```

**GroupDaoImplTest.java:**

```
public class GroupDaoImplTest {

private GroupDaoImpl groupDao = new GroupDaoImpl();
private static Set<Group> groupSet = new HashSet<>();
private static Group group;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws DaoException {
    StudentDaoImpl studentDao = new StudentDaoImpl();
    group = new Group(1, "Group 11");
    group.setStudents(studentDao.retrieveByGroupId(1));
    groupSet.add(group);        
    groupSet.add(new Group(2, "Group 12")); 
}

@Test
public void testInsert() throws DaoException {
    groupDao.insert(new Group(1, "Group 13"), 2);       
}

@Test
public void testUpdate() throws DaoException {
    groupDao.update(new Group(15, "Group 11"));     
}

@Test
public void testDelete() throws DaoException {
    groupDao.delete(new Group(16, "Group 11"));
}

@Test
public void testRetrieve() throws DaoException {        
    assertThat(groupDao.retrieve(1), is(group));        
}

@Test
public void testRetrieveByCathedraId() throws DaoException {        
    assertThat(groupDao.retrieveByCathedraId(1), is(groupSet));
}

@Test
public void testRetrieveAll() throws DaoException {             
    assertThat(groupDao.retrieveAll(), is(groupSet));
}
```

}

and when I execute `testRetrieveAll()` I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <[university.domain.Group@1ef58100, university.domain.Group@1ef5849f]>
     but: was <[university.domain.Group@1ef58100, university.domain.Group@1ef5849f]>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that builds the two Groups you are comparing?

Comment: @EJP just wondering where'd you get that much reputation !

Comment: What do you mean by "links"? Do you mean references?

Comment: DodgyCodeException yes

Comment: Eran add code that u ask

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls GroupDao.retrieve() twice with the same ID and compares the two results?

Comment: DodgyCodeException here u go

Comment: You should create toString() methods for Group and Student so that they can be examined and visually compared more easily in the AssertionError message.

Comment: The Group.equals() method looks fine. I think the groups you are comparing are really not equal, but you can't tell because their toString() method is the default one inherited from Object. If you define Group.toString() to show the id + students.toString(), and define Student.toString() to show id + name + surname, you'll be able to see the actual difference.

Comment: I did it and there is no diference

Comment: Your code looks ok and I can't see where it may be wrong, so I suggest you try single-stepping through the equals methods in a debugger until you find a call that returns false when it should return true.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine by me:

```
Group g1 = new Group(1, "a");
Set<Student> s1 = new HashSet<>();
s1.add(new Student(1, "a", "b"));
g1.setStudents(s1);

Group g2 = new Group(1, "a");
Set<Student> s2 = new HashSet<>();
s2.add(new Student(1, "a", "b"));
g2.setStudents(s2);

System.out.println(g1.equals(g2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `students` field of `group` in your test class is `null`, whereas the `students` field of the group returned by `groupDao.retrieveAll()` always has a non-null `students` set. If there are no students in the group, its `students` field is empty (contains no students), not null.

`Objects.hash()` gives null fields the hash code 0, and the hash code of an empty set is also 0. Therefore the two groups have the same hash code, but they are not equal.

Comment: @shmosel Despite the name,`HashSet`s do check for object equality. They use the hash code to put elements into buckets, but within each bucket they call `equals()` to determine whether elements are equal or not.

Comment: Exactly. Hence my question.

Comment: @shmosel Aha, I think I misunderstood your remark :-). The first thing I noticed about the error message in the question is that both sets contain groups with the same hash codes (`Object.toString()` returns strings of the form class@hashcode), which lead to an initial assumption on my part that the objects are in fact equal and the problem must be elsewhere. I now believe that that assumption was false. So the hash code remark was meant to explain this in case anyone else noticed the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

What result are you expecting when calling the 
Objects.equals(students, castOther.students) ?

I guess, this is going to return **true** only if students field of both Group instances are referencing to exactly one instance of Set.

Comment: So, to make your code work, you should go through the set of students and compare them all for equality instead of doing Objects.equals(students, castOther.students)

Comment: No, Objects.equals(a, b) eventually calls a.equals(b) which, for Sets, calls equals for every element.